# Starting Android AVD crashes with java.awt.HeadlessException

Tags: android, ubuntu-10.04, android-sdk-2.3

Using Android SDK Manager Revision 15 on Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty) with sun-jav6-jdk (6.26) installed. Every configuration I've tried for an AVD is resulting in this exact same behaviour when I try to start it. I've even tried running it with root privelages.

```
java.awt.HeadlessException
at sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit.getScreenResolution(HeadlessToolkit.java:221)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdStartDialog.getMonitorDpi(AvdStartDialog.java:420)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdStartDialog.createDialogContent(AvdStartDialog.java:179)
at com.android.sdkuilib.ui.GridDialog.createDialogArea(GridDialog.java:76)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.createContents(Dialog.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdSelector.onStart(AvdSelector.java:1035)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdSelector.access$600(AvdSelector.java:76)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdSelector$7.widgetSelected(AvdSelector.java:317)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.sdkman2.SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.open(SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.java:158)
at com.android.sdkuilib.repository.SdkUpdaterWindow.open(SdkUpdaterWindow.java:154)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:335)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:307)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:119)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:102)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another workaround that worked for me

```
apt-get purge sun-java*
```

APT installed the openjdk packages automatically by doing that...

Answer (score 4):

I filed a [tools bug 22025](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22025) with this. The exception is in the UI that computes your screen resolution to be able to resize the AVD window, and this is done before the emulator is started.

A workaround is to start the AVD from the command line:

```
$ SDK/tools/emulator @avd_name
$ SDK/tools/emulator -avd avd_name
```

Comment: I purged openjdk, and reinstalled sun-java in attempt to replicate the issue and see if this worked. I was unable to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The apt-get purge didn't do it for me. I didn't have any of the Sun Java packages installed, so it changed nothing. I had only OpenJDK 7. What fixed it was installing OpenJDK 6:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

(Credit [dashxdr](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=22025))