# I can not start Android Emulator in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: android, android-emulator, ubuntu-12.10

I tried running Android emulator in a many of ways: commandline or on AVD interface but it does not run. When I run on the command line it throws this exception:

> java.awt.HeadlessException
>     at sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit.getScreenResolution(HeadlessToolkit.java:221)
>     at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdStartDialog.getMonitorDpi(AvdStartDialog.java:441)
>     at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdStartDialog.createDialogContent(AvdStartDialog.java:189)
>     at com.android.sdkuilib.ui.GridDialog.createDialogArea(GridDialog.java:76)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.createContents(Dialog.java:760)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
>     at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdSelector.onStart(AvdSelector.java:1105)
>     at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdSelector.access$600(AvdSelector.java:84)
>     at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdSelector$7.widgetSelected(AvdSelector.java:331)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
>     at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.AvdManagerWindowImpl1.open(AvdManagerWindowImpl1.java:144)
>     at com.android.sdkuilib.repository.AvdManagerWindow.open(AvdManagerWindow.java:94)
>     at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showAvdManagerWindow(Main.java:369)
>     at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:311)
>     at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:119)
>     at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:102)

My Emulator's android version is 2.3.3.
Someone can help me.
Sorry for my English skill

Comment: This probably isn't what you want to hear, but the Android emulator is just not good. It's riddled with bugs and is inconsistent. The solution to all emulator related problems is to not use the emulator - use a real device.

Comment: have you tried making diferent emulators? I can't make an 4.0 ICS emulator with my Windows 7 but every other work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198077/starting-android-avd-crashes-with-java-awt-headlessexception) StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. My java sdk not compatibility for android emulator.
It work perfectly on Open JDK 6.